# How to split this string to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, delimiter

I have a string:

```
string s = \x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nien\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],[\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E ca\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],[\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nhan\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],[\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E thao\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22
```

I want split this string into an array named "s2", the delimiter is ",0,[]],[". I tried with s.Split() but it only accept the delimiter is a char. How I can do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only overloads of `String.Split` that accept a `string` as the delimiter require an array (`string[]`), so you will want this:

```
string[] s2 = s.Split(new string[] { ",0,[]],[" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

See these overloads:

[String.Split (String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

[String.Split (String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works

```
s.Split(new string[] {"0","[]]","[" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] s2 = s.Split(new string[] { ",0,[]],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting by regular expression should work as well.

```
string[] s2 = Regex.Split(s, ",0,\\[\\]\\],\\[")
```